# EventHandling in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a movieclip in library that has a button inside it. Assume that I had added an `eventListener` to the nested button after adding the movieclip to the stage . Will this listener be automatically removed when I remove the element using removeChild? Is it necessary to use removeEventListener even after removeChild is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the event listener using a weak reference (last parameter to addEventListener I believe) it should be cleaned up. Take care however as this may clean the event listener before you want it to, for instance when going out of scope of wherever the listener was declared.

If it's not a weak reference, you need to clear the event listener yourself as otherwise this means there's a reference to your element and you will have a memory leak.

Comment: So you are saying that the best bet is to not use the weak reference option and clean it up ourself.

Comment: Indeed. 1 use week reference or 2. remove event listener ;)

Comment: @Bobby, yes; the best bet is to always do clean up yourself as you essentially can't know when the GC will run.

Comment: @Ascension Systems: Where did you get that information from? I've been told a number of times during talks and private sessions with Adobe engineers that the GC is non-deterministic and will run using heuristics based on memory allocation, not time. It makes sense, there's little point in wasting CPU cycles on GC unless it's necessary.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion I was looking over a very small chunk of source taken out of context and drew that assumption. I went back to the tamarin source and looked at the whole class and found I was incorrect. Again thanks for questioning me on that, was a very bad assumption lol

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use weak referencing - this is one of the memory leaks in AS3 - GSkinner has a great explanation at http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_weakly_refe.html